# Create full table view with min and max value lookup based on column groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `t1` with 4 columns:

```
f1
f2
quant
rate
```

I need to create a view that contains all records in `t1` but lists the min and max `quant` value with the corresponding `rate` for each `f1` and `f2` group.

I have a solution below, but it seems like a very long workaround. Is there an easier way to achieve these results in SQL Server 2014?

```
--Create min
    Select 
        a.f1
        ,a.f2
        ,b.min_quant
        ,a.rate As min_rate
    Into t1_min
    From t1 As a
    Inner Join (
        Select 
            f1
            ,f2
            ,MIN(quant) As min_quant
        From t1
        Group By f1, f2
    ) As b
        On a.f1 = b.f1
        And a.f2 = b.f2
        And a.quant = b.min_quant

--Create Max
    Select 
        a.f1
        ,a.f2
        ,b.max_quant
        ,a.rate As max_rate
    Into t1_max
    From t1 As a
    Inner Join (
        Select 
            f1
            ,f2
            ,MAX(quant) As max_quant
        From t1
        Group By f1, f2
    ) As b
        On a.f1 = b.f1
        And a.f2 = b.f2
        And a.quant = b.max_quant

--Create Final
    Select
    a.f1
    ,a.f2
    ,a.quant
    ,b.min_quant
    ,c.max_quant
    ,a.rate
    ,b.min_rate
    ,c.max_rate
    From t1 As a
    Left Join t1_min As b
        On a.f1 = b.f1
        And a.f2 = b.f2
    Left Join t1_max As c
        On a.f1 = c.f1
        And a.f2 = c.f2
```

Comment: It would be better to give some sample data and desired output. It is hard to infer what you want from your code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess window functions will do:

```
select
    f1, f2,
    quant,
    min(quant) over(partition by f1, f2) as min_quant,
    max(quant) over(partition by f1, f2) as max_quant,
    rate,
    min(rate) over(partition by f1, f2) as min_rate,
    max(rate) over(partition by f1, f2) as max_rate,
  from t1;
```

Comment: He doesn't want the min and max rate per f1,f2 but the one that corresponds to min\max quant per f1,f2.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to drop those t1_min and t1_max and recreate each time.

This is a simpler way IMHO (but your requirements are vague, what happens when there are multiple min\max values for example. Anyway this at least matches the result you have):

```
SELECT f1, f2, quant, 
  min_quant, min_rate,
  max_quant, max_rate
FROM dbo.t1 t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(quant), MAX(quant) 
    FROM t1 tt WHERE t.f1=tt.f1 AND t.f2=tt.f2) tm(min_quant, max_quant)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT rate FROM t1 tt 
    WHERE t.f1=tt.f1 AND t.f2=tt.f2 AND tt.quant = tm.min_quant) tminr(min_rate)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT rate FROM t1 tt 
    WHERE t.f1=tt.f1 AND t.f2=tt.f2 AND tt.quant = tm.max_quant) tmaxr(max_rate);
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I was trying to get Cross Applies to work in this context. This will definitely help me in the future. For this problem, I found that this took a lot of time to process vs analytic functions.

Comment: @Masasar, yes this is related with data density. If the data density was so that there were many entries for a given f1,f2 (distinct f1, f2 count is not a lot) then cross apply would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a numbering in both directions (ascending and descending) and from both numberings pick the number 1 when joining the numbered records to t1:

```
WITH
  minmax (f1, f2, quant, rate, rn_min, rn_max) AS (
    SELECT f1, f2, quant, rate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f1, f2 ORDER BY quant ASC),
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f1, f2 ORDER BY quant DESC)
    FROM t1
  )
SELECT t1.f1, t1.f2, t1.quant, t1.rate,
  mi.quant AS min_quant, mi.rate AS min_rate,
  ma.quant AS max_quant, ma.rate AS max_rate
FROM t1
  INNER JOIN minmax mi ON t1.f1 = mi.f1 AND t1.f2 = mi.f2 AND mi.rn_min = 1
  INNER JOIN minmax ma ON t1.f1 = ma.f1 AND t1.f2 = ma.f2 AND ma.rn_max = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given good leads from the other answers, I discovered [Analytic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that creates desired output with FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE().

```
Select
    f1
    ,f2
    ,quant
    ,MIN(quant) Over(Partition By f1, f2) As min_quant
    ,MAX(quant) Over(Partition By f1, f2) As max_quant
    ,rate
    ,FIRST_VALUE(rate) Over(Partition By f1, f2 Order By quant) As min_rate
    ,LAST_VALUE(rate) Over(Partition By f1, f2 Order By quant RANGE Between CURRENT ROW And UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) As max_rate
From t1
Order By f1, f2, quant
```